# Import expression involving cosine and sin

Tags: export

I have a list of elements that contains numbers like `2 (Cos[\[Pi]/9] + I Sin[\[Pi]/9])`. However, when I export the list and call it later, I end up with elements of the form `{"2*(Cos[Pi/9]", "+", "I*Sin[Pi/9])"}`. Is there a way to import the original numbers and get the original numbers back insted of the weird thing `{"2*(Cos[Pi/9]", "+", "I*Sin[Pi/9])"}`?

I am exporting a list in mathematica as follows `List1={2 (-I Cos[\[Pi]/18] - Sin[\[Pi]/18]), 2 (-I Cos[\[Pi]/18] + 
   Sin[\[Pi]/18]), 2 (1/2 - (I Sqrt[3])/2), 2 (Cos[(2 \[Pi])/9] - 
   I Sin[(2 \[Pi])/9]), 2 (Cos[\[Pi]/9] - I Sin[\[Pi]/9]), {2.7297 + 
  0. I, -2. + 0. I, -1.89575 + 0.616863 I, -1.89575 - 
  0.616863 I, -1.59507 + 1.16624 I, -1.59507 - 1.16624 I, -1.13262 + 
  1.58703 I, -1.13262 - 1.58703 I, 1.80793 + 0.698449 I, 
 1.80793 - 0.698449 I, -0.56236 + 1.83087 I, -0.56236 - 1.83087 I, 
 0.0442446 + 1.86687 I}`, which I obtained from some previous calculations. I am also saving it as a .dat file.

I am just using Export command and to import it I am just using Import command to retrieve it.

Comment: Can you give more information about *how* and *what* you are importing and exporting? Is the list a *Mathematica* list? Is it the output of a calculation? Are you using `DumpSave`, `Export`, etc.? What is the file format? Are you using `Import`? `Get`? Are you specifying *how* you `Import`? Etc.

Comment: Sorry for the little information, I  hope the extra info I added helps, let me know if you would like to know something more.

Comment: Why not export as ".m" instead of ".dat"?

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ReadList["foo.txt"]` to read Mathematica expressions

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
list1 = {2 (-I Cos[\[Pi]/18] - Sin[\[Pi]/18]), 
   2 (-I Cos[\[Pi]/18] + Sin[\[Pi]/18]), 2 (1/2 - (I Sqrt[3])/2), 
   2 (Cos[(2 \[Pi])/9] - I Sin[(2 \[Pi])/9]), 
   2 (Cos[\[Pi]/9] - I Sin[\[Pi]/9]), {2.7297 + 0. I, -2. + 0. I, -1.89575 + 
     0.616863 I, -1.89575 - 0.616863 I, -1.59507 + 1.16624 I, -1.59507 - 
     1.16624 I, -1.13262 + 1.58703 I, -1.13262 - 1.58703 I, 
    1.80793 + 0.698449 I, 
    1.80793 - 0.698449 I, -0.56236 + 1.83087 I, -0.56236 - 1.83087 I, 
    0.0442446 + 1.86687 I}};
Export["foo.txt", list1];
myList = ReadList["foo.txt"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
myList - list1
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
(myList - list1) // Chop
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

If you have numbers in sin and cos you can fix the problem by evaluating the sin and the cos with **N[yourlist]**...
The import returns a string, so you have to interpreter it, with **ToExpression[...]**.

**Example:**

```
list={2 (-I Cos[\[Pi]/18]-Sin[\[Pi]/18]),2 (-I Cos[\[Pi]/18]+Sin[\[Pi]/18]),2 (1/2-(I Sqrt[3])/2),2 (Cos[(2 \[Pi])/9]-I Sin[(2 \[Pi])/9]),2 (Cos[\[Pi]/9]-I Sin[\[Pi]/9]),2.7297+0. I,-2.+0. I,-1.89575+0.616863 I,-1.89575-0.616863 I,-1.59507+1.16624 I,-1.59507-1.16624 I,-1.13262+1.58703 I,-1.13262-1.58703 I,1.80793+0.698449 I,1.80793-0.698449 I,-0.56236+1.83087 I,-0.56236-1.83087 I,0.0442446+1.86687 I};

list=N[list]

Export["list.dat",list]

importedList=ToExpression[Import["list.dat"]][[All,1]]
```